# Xpath: how to find a div using the elements in the div

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

i writed this line of code (i know it isn't correct)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(div[contains(string(),"Example_String"))]').click()
```

i need to ***find the div that contains a div that contains a string***. how to can i do that?

*sorry for grammatical errors, i'm not english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about JaSON's solutions, neither of them doesn't look like a valid xpath to me...

try this, it should work for you:

```
//div[div[contains(text(), 'Example_String')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
'//div[contains(div,"Example_String")]
```

for *child* `div` or

```
'//div[contains(.//div,"Example_String")]
```

for *descendant* `div`

Answer (score 0):

If the child div is an immediate child of parent div -
`//div/div[contains(text(),'SOME_TEXT')]`

If the child div is somewhere far inside the parent div -
`//div//div[contains(text(),'SOME_TEXT')]` OR `//div[contains(text(),'SOME_TEXT')]`